# Is Smooks supports reading of Header-Detail-Trailer structured fixed length files?

Tags: java, file, parsing

I am looking for a fixed length file parser and i came across Smooks. Smooks has ability to read flat file (without segmentation) but in my case i have file with following structure.

HD___________
DTL__________
DTL__________
TRL__________

Is Smooks has support to read fixed legth file with this kind of structure?

Answer (score 0):

Via Smooks, the easiest way might be to use the regex reader, which basically lets you parse any format that can be described via regex. There's an example in the smooks docs somewhere.

However ... if the format is as easy as you outline above, maybe using anything more than regular Java is a bit of overkill.

Comment: I am working on other formats (EDI,CSV,XML) as well, so instead of recreating something Smooks will do work for me. If possible please share any example that will really help.

Comment: Okay ... well in that case, I think check out the regex reader.